# Protobuf-net create .proto with many classes & interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

Using: protobuf-net
I'm trying to use the:

```
string proto = Serializer.GetProto<YourType>();
```

But something the output I get is wrong.
I want to pass an interface so the client can have the methods to use & 2 class.

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Whatever
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string? Text { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Numb
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int? Num { get; set; }
}

[Service("Duplex")]
public interface IDuplex
{
    public IAsyncEnumerable<Whatever> Duplex(Numb num, CallContext context = default);
}
```

So I'm doing something along the line of:

```
using var writer = new StreamWriter("proto.proto");
writer.WriteLine(Serializer.GetProto<IDuplex>());
writer.WriteLine(Serializer.GetProto<Numb>());
writer.WriteLine(Serializer.GetProto<Whatever>());
writer.Close();
```

But I get:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package ConsoleApp1;

message IDuplex {
}

syntax = "proto3";
package ConsoleApp1;

message Numb {
   int32 Num = 1;
}

syntax = "proto3";
package ConsoleApp1;

message Whatever {
   string Text = 1;
}
```

Instead of something like:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package ConsoleApp1;

Service IDuplex {
   rpc Duplex(Numb) returns(Whatever);
}

message Numb {
   int32 Num = 1;
}

message Whatever {
   string Text = 1;
}
```

How can I chain many classes so I won't have that many:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package ConsoleApp1;
```

And create service to write into the same file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

protobuf-net by itself doesn't know about services; for that you need protobuf-net.Grpc, and in this case: protobuf-net.Grpc.Reflection, which has the `SchemaGenerator` type; usage:

```
var gen = new SchemaGenerator();
var schema = gen.GetSchema(typeof(IDuplex));
Console.WriteLine(schema);
```

This gives:

```cs
syntax = "proto3";

message Numb {
   int32 Num = 1;
}
message Whatever {
   string Text = 1;
}
service Duplex {
   rpc Duplex (Numb) returns (stream Whatever);
}
```

(the main reason that `protobuf-net.Grpc.Reflection` is a separate package here is that `protobuf-net.Grpc` only demands protobuf-net v2.x, but this feature requires v3.x APIs - hence `protobuf-net.Grpc.Reflection` forces a protobuf-net v3 transitive)